# All checkbox checked by trigger - orbeon/xforms

Tags: checkbox, orbeon, xforms

Here it's my source code:

```
<xh:head>
    <xh:title>Newsletter</xh:title>
    <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true">

        <!-- Main instance -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance">
            <form>
                    <News_choice>
                        <Sub_select>zamawiam</Sub_select>

                    </News_choice>
                    <Zamowienie>
                        <Zamowienie_wybor/>
                        <Select_all/>
                        <Deselect_all/>
                    </Zamowienie>
                    <Rezygnacja>
                        <Rezygnacja_wybor/>
                        <SelectAll_1/>
                        <Deselect_all_1/>
                    </Rezygnacja>
                    <Mail>
                        <Email/>
                    </Mail>
            </form>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Bindings -->
        <xf:bind id="fr-form-binds" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">
            <xf:bind id="News_choice-bind" name="News_choice" ref="News_choice">
                <xf:bind id="Sub_select-bind" ref="Sub_select" name="Sub_select"/>

            </xf:bind>
            <xf:bind id="Zamowienie-bind" ref="Zamowienie" name="Zamowienie"
                     relevant="$Sub_select = 'zamawiam'">
                <xf:bind id="Zamowienie_wybor-bind" ref="Zamowienie_wybor" name="Zamowienie_wybor"/>
                <xf:bind id="Select_all-bind" ref="Select_all" name="Select_all"/>
                <xf:bind id="Deselect_all-bind" ref="Deselect_all" name="Deselect_all"/>
            </xf:bind>
            <xf:bind id="Mail-bind" ref="Mail" name="Mail">
                <xf:bind id="Email-bind" ref="Email" name="Email"
                         constraint="matches(.,'^[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}') or string-length(.) = 0"/>
            </xf:bind>
            <xf:bind id="Rezygnacja-bind" ref="Rezygnacja" name="Rezygnacja"
                     relevant="$Sub_select = 'rezygnuje'">
                <xf:bind id="Rezygnacja_wybor-bind" ref="Rezygnacja_wybor" name="Rezygnacja_wybor"/>
                <xf:bind id="SelectAll_1-bind" ref="SelectAll_1" name="SelectAll_1"/>
                <xf:bind id="Deselect_all_1-bind" ref="Deselect_all_1" name="Deselect_all_1"/>
            </xf:bind>
        </xf:bind>

        <!-- Metadata -->
        <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-metadata">
            <metadata>
                <application-name>Subskrypcja</application-name>
                <form-name>Newsletter</form-name>
                <title xml:lang="pl">Newsletter</title>
                <description xml:lang="pl"/>
            </metadata>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Attachments -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-attachments">
            <attachments>
                <css mediatype="text/css" filename="" size=""/>
                <pdf mediatype="application/pdf" filename="" size=""/>
            </attachments>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- All form resources -->
        <!-- Don't make readonly by default in case a service modifies the resources -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-resources" xxf:readonly="false">
            <resources>
                <resource xml:lang="pl">
                    <Email>
                        <label>&lt;b&gt;&lt;center&gt;Prosimy o podanie adresu e-mail, pod który ma zostać wysłany link aktywacyjny.&lt;/center&gt;&lt;/b&gt;</label>
                        <hint/>
                    </Email>
                    <Rezygnacja_wybor>
                       <item id='1'>
                            <label>Dostawy</label>
                            <value>dostawy</value>
                            <hint/>
                        </item>
                        <item id='2'>
                            <label>Konsultacje</label>
                            <value>konsultacje</value>
                            <hint/>
                        </item>
                        <item id='3'>
                            <label>Ogłoszenia urzędowe</label>
                            <value>ogloszenia</value>
                            <hint/>
                        </item>
                        <item id='4'>                  
                            <label>Usługi</label>
                            <value>uslugi</value>
                            <hint/>
                        </item>
                        <item id='5'>                  
                            <label>Informacje o wynikach naboru</label>
                            <value>info</value>
                            <hint/>
                        </item>
                        <item id='6'>                  
                            <label>Nabór - Urząd Miasta</label>
                            <value>nabor</value>
                            <hint/>
                        </item>
                        <item id='7'>                  
                            <label>Roboty budowlane</label>
                            <value>roboty</value>
                            <hint/>
                        </item>
                        <label>&lt;center&gt;&lt;b&gt;Prosimy o wybranie, jakich działów niniejszego portalu ma dotyczyć rezygnacja z powiadomień.&lt;/center&gt;&lt;/b&gt;</label>
                        <hint/>
                    </Rezygnacja_wybor>
                    <SelectAll_1>
                        <label>Zaznacz wszystkie</label>
                        <hint/>
                    </SelectAll_1>
                    <Deselect_all_1>
                        <label>Odznacz wszystkie</label>
                        <hint/>
                    </Deselect_all_1>
                    <Zamowienie_wybor>



                        <label>&lt;center&gt;&lt;b&gt;Prosimy o wybranie, jakich działów niniejszego portalu mają dotyczyć powiadomienia:&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/center&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;/b&gt;</label>
                        <hint/>
                        <item id='1'>
                            <label>Dostawy</label>
                            <value>dostawy</value>
                            <hint/>
                        </item>
                        <item id='2'>
                            <label>Konsultacje</label>
                            <value>konsultacje</value>
                            <hint/>
                        </item>
                        <item id='3'>
                            <label>Ogłoszenia urzędowe</label>
                            <value>ogloszenia</value>
                            <hint/>
                        </item>
                        <item id='4'>                  
                            <label>Usługi</label>
                            <value>uslugi</value>
                            <hint/>
                        </item>
                        <item id='5'>                  
                            <label>Informacje o wynikach naboru</label>
                            <value>info</value>
                            <hint/>
                        </item>
                        <item id='6'>                  
                            <label>Nabór - Urząd Miasta</label>
                            <value>nabor</value>
                            <hint/>
                        </item>
                        <item id='7'>                  
                            <label>Roboty budowlane</label>
                            <value>roboty</value>
                            <hint/>
                        </item>
                    </Zamowienie_wybor>
                    <Select_all>
                        <label>Zaznacz wszystkie</label>
                        <hint/>
                    </Select_all>
                    <Deselect_all>
                        <label>Odznacz wszystkie</label>
                        <hint/>
                    </Deselect_all>
                    <Sub_select>



                        <label>&lt;b&gt;&lt;center&gt;Aby stać się subskrybentem powiadomień należy zaznaczyć "zamawiam subskrycję". W celu rezygnacji prosimy o wybranie opcji "rezygnuję z subskrypcji".&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/center&gt;</label>
                        <hint/>
                        <item>
                            <label>Zamawiam subskrypcję</label>
                            <value>zamawiam</value>
                            <hint/>
                        </item>
                        <item>
                            <label>Rezygnuję z subskrypcji</label>
                            <value>rezygnuje</value>
                            <hint/>
                        </item>
                    </Sub_select>
                    <News_choice>
                        <label>Subskrypcja</label>
                    </News_choice>
                    <Zamowienie>
                        <label>Zamówienie subskrypcji</label>
                        <help/>
                    </Zamowienie>
                    <Rezygnacja>
                        <label>Rezygnacja z subskrypcji</label>
                        <help/>
                    </Rezygnacja>
                    <Mail>
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <help/>
                    </Mail>

                </resource>
            </resources>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Utility instances for services -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-service-request-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <request/>
        </xf:instance>

        <xf:instance id="fr-service-response-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <response/>
        </xf:instance>

    </xf:model>
</xh:head>
<xh:body>
    <fr:view>
        <fr:body xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl"
                 xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
                 xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline">
            <fr:section id="News_choice-control" bind="News_choice-bind">
                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/News_choice/label"/>
                <fr:grid>
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:select1 id="Sub_select-control" appearance="full" bind="Sub_select-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/Sub_select/label" mediatype="text/html"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/Sub_select/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>


                                <xf:itemset ref="$form-resources/Sub_select/item">
                                    <xf:label ref="label"/>
                                    <xf:value ref="value"/>
                                    <xf:hint ref="hint"/>
                                </xf:itemset>
                            </xf:select1>

                        </xh:td>
                        <xh:td/>
                    </xh:tr>
                </fr:grid>
            </fr:section>
            <fr:section id="Zamowienie-control" bind="Zamowienie-bind">
                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/Zamowienie/label"/>
                <fr:grid>
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:select id="Zamowienie_wybor-control" appearance="full" bind="Zamowienie_wybor-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/Zamowienie_wybor/label" mediatype="text/html"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/Zamowienie_wybor/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>



                                <xf:itemset ref="$form-resources/Zamowienie_wybor/item">
                                    <xf:label ref="label"/>
                                    <xf:value ref="value"/>
                                    <xf:value ref="hint"/>
                                </xf:itemset>
                            </xf:select>
                        </xh:td>
                        <xh:td/>
                    </xh:tr>
                </fr:grid>
                <fr:grid>
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:trigger id="Select_all-control" bind="Select_all-bind">

                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/Select_all/label"/>

                        <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/Select_all/hint"/>
                               <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>

                            </xf:trigger>
                        </xh:td>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:trigger id="Deselect_all-control" bind="Deselect_all-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/Deselect_all/label"/>

                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/Deselect_all/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>

                            </xf:trigger>
                        </xh:td>
                        <xh:td/>
                        <xh:td/>
                        <xh:td/>
                        <xh:td/>
                    </xh:tr>
                </fr:grid>
            </fr:section>
            <fr:section id="Rezygnacja-control" bind="Rezygnacja-bind">
                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/Rezygnacja/label"/>
                <fr:grid>
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:select id="Rezygnacja_wybor-control" appearance="full" bind="Rezygnacja_wybor-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/Rezygnacja_wybor/label" mediatype="text/html"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/Rezygnacja_wybor/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>


                                <xf:itemset ref="$form-resources/Rezygnacja_wybor/item">
                                    <xf:label ref="label"/>
                                    <xf:value ref="value"/>
                                    <xf:value ref="hint"/>
                                </xf:itemset>
                            </xf:select>
                        </xh:td>
                        <xh:td/>
                    </xh:tr>
                </fr:grid>
                <fr:grid>
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:trigger id="SelectAll_1-control" bind="SelectAll_1-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/SelectAll_1/label"/>

                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/SelectAll_1/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>

                            </xf:trigger>
                        </xh:td>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:trigger id="Deselect_all_1-control" bind="Deselect_all_1-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/Deselect_all_1/label"/>

                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/Deselect_all_1/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>

                            </xf:trigger>
                        </xh:td>
                        <xh:td/>
                        <xh:td/>
                        <xh:td/>
                        <xh:td/>
                    </xh:tr>
                </fr:grid>
            </fr:section>
            <fr:section id="Mail-control" bind="Mail-bind">
                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/Mail/label"/>
                <fr:grid>
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:input id="Email-control" bind="Email-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/Email/label" mediatype="text/html"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/Email/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>                    
                            </xf:input>
                        </xh:td>
                        <xh:td/>
                    </xh:tr>
                </fr:grid>
            </fr:section>
        </fr:body>
```

I have setup a trigger called "Select_all" for check all checkboxes in the "Zamowienie_wybor" but I don't know exacly how to do it in a proper way. 
Second trigger called "Deselect_all" should remove all checkboxes for "Zamowienie_wybor" field.
I try to use setvalue action but it won't work.
I would be grateful for all advices.

Answer (score 0):

You do this by using the [`xxf:itemset()`](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-xpath-functions#TOC-xxf:itemset-) function, which returns all the information related to the checkboxes. With that function, you can get the "value" for each checkbox, concatenate the values, and set that as the value for the control, as a result selecting all the checkboxes. And of course, the exact same code would work for any selection control allowing multiple values to be selected.

You can see [this full example](https://gist.github.com/avernet/f40054138a84a49c31e6#file-gistfile1-xml-L102), with the "interesting part" highlighted: